# Is search button not required anymore?

Tags: search

It seems that most sites have abandoned explicit search button, assuming that users are used to “hit Enter for search” interaction.

Amazon still uses it:

[image]

But e.g. Apple does not:

[image]

Is there some kind of research that supports the button can be dropped?

Answer (score 3):

Not all users know that a form can be implicitly submitted by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> – certainly not in the research I’ve seen.

It can also be a barrier for mobile users because omitting the button means they have to rely on a button existing within the onscreen keyboard.

And I‘m pretty sure that not all do anyway. A quick search found this:

[image]

The same sites that omit the submit button, make space for a magnifying glass icon so users realise it's a search box more easily.

Search boxes often omit a (visible) label (again to save space). A button/icon acts as a quasi-label for sighted users.

May as well combine the icon and button together because it works for everyone.

*(Note: if your search form has more than just one input (like a scoped search) then omitting the submit button stops users from being able to submit the form by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.)*